# Why will my jQuery not work when I add the .sqrt()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a grid of divs and need to take the square root of the users input to find the height and width needed to make a square. This is the code I have doing it:

```
$('#size').click(function(){
 $('.container').empty();
 var big = prompt('Enter the desired number of cubes');
 var final = $(big).sqrt();
 drawGrid(final);
```

Here is a link to my whole project on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ztwsptys/
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the browsers console is your friend -- anyway you have an error ***  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sqrt is not a function  *** -- -https://jsfiddle.net/m2qs080m/ -- you need to do Math.sqrt(big); -- https://jsfiddle.net/j0hfy579/

Answer (score 0):

Just do `Math.sqrt(big)`. Assuming that you are sure that `big` is a `Number`. You don't need to go crazy with wrapping your `big` variable with jQuery. Make sure that `big` is actually a number. If you read the user input I can bet that the value is read as a string. You would need to `ParseFloat` or `ParseInt` it depending what kind of value you are expecting from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.sqrt(big);` instead of `$(big).sqrt();`